# How to automatically install SqlLocalDB after installing my C# app

Tags: c#, setup-project, localdb, silent-installer

I want to create an installer for my C# application and add SqlLocalDB to it to install it automatically after the application is installed, how i do that?
If SqlLocalDB can be installed in silent mode that's even better.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Make sure to read SQL Server local db license Information regarding redistribution.

Comment: Do you *have to* use LocalDb? If not, [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/) might be a good alternative. It is compact, full featured and easy to manage DB. Since it is single file based, it is easy to distribute/install along with executables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to **download** the `SqlLocalDB` executable or the .msi from Microsoft Website then include it in the setup scripts.

`Inno-Setup Compiler` can work fine. So along with your C# program files you will need to attach the SqlLocalDB executable.

Here is a link to [Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isdl.php)

A link to [SQLLocalDb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Thank you for the method, I did what you told me, and I added these in the setup scripts: " Filename: "{app}\SqlLocalDB.msi"; Parameters: "/silent"; Flags: waituntilterminated skipifdoesntexist; StatusMsg: "SqlLocalDB installation. Please wait..." ", 
but this problem appears to me when it reaches the installation of SqlLocalDB: https://ibb.co/FD1BSB0
Although the installation of SqlLocalDB works without problems when I open it from the outside

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I guess the issue will be more related to settings especially admin rights to install the SqlLocalDB. I will check further and assist

Comment: I found the solution, I made this modification in the setup scripts:
"  Filename: {cmd}; Parameters: " /c msiexec /i SqlLocalDB.msi /qn IACCEPTSQLLOCALDBLICENSETERMS=YES";  WorkingDir: "{app}";   StatusMsg: "SqlLocalDB installation. Please wait...";  Flags:  runhidden waituntilterminated;  "  and it worked without problems, thank you for the method and thank you for helping me.